# What does "made him to be sin" mean?

Tags: 2-corinthians

> For our sake he **made him to be sin** who knew no sin, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God.—2<sup>nd</sup> Corinthians 5:21 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/2+Corinthians+5/))

Does it mean that he was made to be sin incarnate, just as we say he was love incarnate? Is this a real transformation or just a figure of speech to say he paid the penalty for sin?

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! This verse is classically considered difficult to exposit. If you ask about the *exegesis* or *meaning* of this phrase, this could be a really good question. As it stands, it is not a great question for this site because [one link](http://bible.cc/2_corinthians/5-21.htm) will gave you the translation of many versions (though none of them may help you understand it). Also, I recommend quoting less of the passage in the question body.

Comment: @Dan... Welcome, I edited it according to Kazark's comments, if that doesn't work we can revert it somehow.

Comment: I was afraid to ask for the meaning as that leads to opinions.  I am looking for possibilities. However at this point, I'd be happy with anything :D

Comment: I agree with @Kazark that this really isn't a very interesting translation question.  The English equivalent is relatively straightforward.  Therefore, I removed the [tag:translation].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I understand this to mean](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-do-you-convert-somebody-to-christianity/578#578) that, while Jesus was (and is) perfect, He was made sin *for a time* for us on the cross. That is, He took [the punishment that bought us peace](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2053:5&version=NIV1984) upon Himself, so that we (who are [born again](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:3&version=NIV1984)) are not punished for our sins.

Even more scandalous, we take on His righteousness, the *righteousness of God!* No wonder Grace is called Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

Consider one of the goats on the Day of Atonement (*Yom ha-Kippurim*).

In Lev. 16:21-22, it is written,

> <sup>21</sup> And Aharon shall lay both his hands upon the head of the live goat and confess over it all the iniquities of the children of Israel, and all their transgressions in all their sins, putting them upon the head of the goat, and he shall send it away by the hand of a fit man into the wilderness, <sup>22</sup> and the goat shall bear upon it all their iniquities to a land cut-off, and he shall let the goat go in the wilderness.

Here we see that a goat, who otherwise "knew no sin," had "all the iniquities of the children of Israel" imputed to it, and the life of the goat was a substitution for the life of the people of Israel. Likewise, our sins were imputed to Christ, just as his righteousness is imputed to those of us who are "in Christ."

Answer (score 0):

God was willing for us to appear in the sinful flesh it is written. Meaning as a human He appeared as a sinner, without really having any sin, but experiencing having sin. That was part of the crucifixion, when as a human He cried out 'My God, My God, why have you forsaken Me."
As if God the Father would ever forsake his Son... or it meant that the Son had forgotten Who He was, overtaken by the human appearance, which is also part of the cross.

This is written as an example for God's spiritual development in us:

"And Jesus grew in wisdom, stature, and favor with God and man."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).